# Post a photo - DesktopApp

Tags: facebook, image-uploading

I'm developing a desktop application which uploads a selected photo to an user wall. I already did the whole code and it uploads it correctly but I have some issues when validating my app with Facebook Review.

They ask for a web canvas which I dont need and i would like to know how could I validate my app so I can use the publish action. As I said my code works fine and it uploads a photo on my wall but that photo is hidden to any other user probably because the app isnt validated.

I really need help with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Desktop apps should submit a Web platform and include detailed
>   screenshots or a screencast of the integration.

So remove the Canvas platform (it sounds like you added it) and add the website platform instead and submit a detailed explanation of how your app integrates with the Facebook Platform and how the permissions you submit for review for are used.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/requirements